# Datatable datarow in Linq

Tags: .net, linq, datatable, linq-to-objects

i have a datatable having a column say column1,it contains many rows which will be like

```
rows[0]=1001000
rows[1]=1000001
```

etc;
what i wanted to achieve is convert 0  with space using LINQ.ie; the expected result will be like

```
rows[0]=1  4   
rows[1]=1     7
```

etc;

i have a linq code for concatinating different colums and then doing the function.But i wanted to do calculation in a single row.My code is

```
var rows = dtFilter.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(row => 
        string.Join("",
            dtFilter.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
               .Select(col => row.Field<string>(col) == "0" ? " " : (col.Ordinal + 1).ToString()))
    )
    .ToList();
```

Comment: What `rows[0]=1001000` means? You have row with single column?

Comment: yes single column,but several rows.... i need to do calculation in each row and store data in a list

Comment: You need list of rows, or list of strings?

Answer (score 1):

Select value from first column of each row, then replace zeros with white spaces and convert result to list:

```
List<string> result = dtFilter.AsEnumerable()
                              .Select(r => r.Field<string>(0))
                              .Select(s => s.Replace("0", " "))
                              .ToList();
```

Comment: your answer works sergey... but i have a slight change in my question...pls check

Answer (score 1):

something like that

```
var elements = new []{"1001000", "1000001"};

var result = elements
             .Select(m => string.Join("", m.Select((x, i) => (x == '1' ? (i+1).ToString() :" "))));
```

so with your code

```
var result = dtFilter
                .AsEnumerable()
                .Select(r => r.Field<string>(0))
                .Select(s => string.Join("", 
                                     s.Select((x, i) => x == '1' 
                                                        ? (i+1).ToString()
                                                        : " "))
                 );
```

Add a little `.ToList()` at the end if you need, of course

**EDIT**

What's happening in the second Select :

when you do a `Select` on a string, it's projected to an `IEnumerable<char>`.

Then, there's an overload of [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) where the selector parameter is a `Func<TSource, Int32, TResult>` . The second parameter of the `Func` represents the index of the source elements.

So for each char in our string, we do

If it's equal to 1, get the index of the char in the string (+1, at it's starting from 0). Which we can do using the second parameter of the `Func` (`i` in this case, while `x` represents the char)

Else, get a white space.

So every char in the `IEnumerable<char>` is computed this way.

And now, we've got an `IEnumerable<char>` with our "transformed characters".

We do a `string.Join` on that `IEnumerable<char>` to get a string back.

Comment: @AnilkumarM I hope so ;)

Comment: can u convert this to vb?